# CSS issue between <h:commandLink> and <h:commandButton> for same style

Tags: html, css, jsf

In my sample application am having 3 action  buttons in bottom  of JSF page  and it's designed by 2  command button and one by command link . the problem is I gave same style  class for these 3 , but command buttons displaying correctly in single line but command link not coming in same line.

Example  in this page  A is by  and B,c are by

```
-----------------------------------------
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |  
|                                        |
|                        ----- -----     |
|                 -----  | B | | c |     |
|                 | A |  ----- -----     |   
|                 -----                  |
-----------------------------------------
```

I need to display in same single line. Style class for these buttons are.

```
.ButtonStyle{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding:1px 4px 1px 4px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Coding for these 3 is:

```
<div align="right'>
 <h:commandLink id="" action=".."  value="A" styleClass="ButtonStyle"/> 
 <h:commandButton id="" action=".."  value="B" styleClass="ButtonStyle"/>
 <h:commandButton id="" action=".."  value="C" styleClass="ButtonStyle"/>
</div>
```

The problem  which I found is in `<h:commandlink>` style is not match with `<h:commandbutton>`.

Can any one help me to come out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get firebug and try to analyse the css of the elements an their containers. Your Links and Buttons might inherit from other css-definitions.

Comment: yeah thank you ,  you are correct,  actually am tried with  firebug early , from that only I came to know this  problem .

Answer (score 4):

Try this (I'm guessing a bit because I'm not familar with JSF):

```
.ButtonStyle {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

The default `vertical-align` is `baseline`, which would look like your ASCII art.

Comment: fine , I Tried this and its almost working what am expected, thanks buddy